# How to disable browser throbber?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page with tabbed navigation and I want to stop the browser throbber ( page loading indicator ), because I've customized my own and it's not good when they both start spinning, so I want to turn off the throbber in my browser and left only this that I'm displaying in my page. I saw the same approach from Twitter, but I didn't found any solution in the web.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry for the question but can you give me more info what's the connection between browser indicator and cursor ? Because I want to disable not the spinning mouse cursor, but the browser loading indication in the browser's tab.

Comment: No problem! Don't worry I already took care of that, because my loader is well positioned and also there are other visual features that care for user to understand that the page is loading, so is there a way to disable that and also to disable it cross browser?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to natively access control the loading element of the browser through javascript or otherwise.

The question you should ask yourself is: *Why is my page taking so long to load?*

If the browser loading indicator is running for an inordinate amount of time, the only way you can really stop it is by **OPTIMIZING YOUR PAGE**.

What that would take, in your case, is uncertain as you have not provided a link where we could investigate and give you suggestions for optimization.

Comment: No my page is loading normally, it's not slow I just want to make customization, because it's not good from design point to have 2 page loading indicators ( mine and the browser's one )